# Parsed Json (jackson) to objects data saving

Tags: android, json, arraylist, jackson

To get Data for my application, I parse a Json file, with Jackson, to (lists of) custom Objects. When I start my app, I check if there is a new Json file available and ask the user if they want to download it, else I use the "old" Json file. But every time I start my app I parse the Json. Then I use the Application Class to save my list of objects an go to my data when I want, most of the time I only need one object.

From the huge list, with multiple layer nested object, I create a simple "flat" arraylist of custom objects in which I put only the data I need to create listviews (name, id, second text and url of picture). When something is clicked, i use the id to get all the data.

Parsing this whole Json file every time is pretty time consuming and makes the startup time of my application long. Ofcourse, this sucks. 
And having this huge list of custom objects saved in Application Class fills a lot of memory of my device, and sometimes after some use the class gets killed, and I need to reparse again.

Is there a way I don't need to reparse all my data?
I  hoped for a process like this:

- new Json file
- first time parse total JSON to list of multilayered custom objects
- create simple list for listviews
- delete/clear the big list
- some clever way to get only one of the giant items, without keeping the whole list in my memory. (maybe something with Jackson).
- on destroying of the application maybe save the simple list, i read something about parceable or serializable?

Anyone knows how to achieve this? 
Or has an other awesome idea?

Answer (score 1):

Jackson has a streaming api.  Also you can parse the json in a AsyncTask (in the background) and update your user interface once the new data is ready

Comment: yeah thats how i load my data during the startup

Comment: Is is possible to present the user with an interface while the AsyncTask continues to process data in the background?  At least this way you won't piss them off.  I agree that SQLite is probably a faster solution for you.  I understand this means re-tooling some of your stuff but it might be worth it

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably store the data in a SQLite database, in line with how the Android platform was designed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to streaming Jackson API (which is very fast, but still has to scan through most of the content), perhaps you could just save things in different files, one per entry? Or, if there is a way to group things, in multiple files each having some subset?

Of course, if you really have tons of entries, use of SQLite as Bruce suggested makes lots of sense.